# String generated using double quotes not getting generated in string pool

Tags: java, string

I am try to execute below lines of code. My understanding was both both #1 and #2 should generate string in String pool and hence there should not be any difference in both the executions, but when I analysed the Heap dump, in case of intern() string were being generated in String pool(can be interpreted by limited number of string objects) but in case of #1 String are being generated on Heap(as large number of string objects are there in heap dump) and system is going out of memory faster than the previous case. Can somebody explain why it is so? I am using java 6 to execute below lines of code.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LotsOfStrings {

private static final LinkedList<String> LOTS_OF_STRINGS = new     LinkedList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                String s= "String " + j;
                LOTS_OF_STRINGS.add(s);  // #1
               //LOTS_OF_STRINGS.add(new String("String " + j).intern());  //#2
            }
        }
        iteration++;
        System.out.println("Survived Iteration: " + iteration);
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Heap dump object screenshot in case if intern
[intern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcuFQ.png)

Heap dump object screenshot in case of #1

[string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P8oo.png)

Comment: String got a reference from a string pool only if its available in pool otherwise its create a string in Heap.

Comment: During first execution of inner loop it should generate 1000 unique Strings String 0....to ....String 999. After this, should not the program use references created during first execution in all subsequent execution of inner loop as the Strings reference should be available in String pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a String without interning it, it just goes to the heap. So there can be multiple copies of equal strings. If you intern the string, there will be only one string for each equality class.

Creating the string `"String" + j` multiple times for the same `j` is much more memory consuming without interning the strings.

Interning saves memory, but it also can slow down the program, because every string is held in some kind of HashSet and creating a string implies looking up if it already exists in that HashSet.

Note: Some strings are interned automatically, e.g. String literals in Source Code.

Comment: do you mean string created as String s= "nothing"; will  not be automatically created in string pool? What my understanding is if a string is created using new operator(String s= new String("nothing")) it will be created on Heap and if string is created using double quotes(String s = "nothing") it will be by default created in string pool in permgen space. A string can be moved from heap to string pool using intern() call on string. Please correct me if something is not correct in my understanding

Comment: Up to my knowledge, a string is only automatically interned if it is a compile time constant (which "String" + j is not). Please point me to an appropriate source if I am wrong.

Comment: This is what I was not aware of that a string needs to be compiled time constant to be generated in String pool. Thanks for you  help.